# I would like to use iMac as a display, but without loading an OS

Tags: display, imac, target-display

I have a late 2009 27" iMac, but recently the internal hard drive completely died. When I try to power it up, the iMac gets stuck on the white Apple loading screen. So instead I would now like to use it just as a display.

Is there a way to do this without replacing the internal hard drive? I have used it as a display before when it was working, so I know it can be used that way.

Answer (score 3):

If your main priority is just not to replace the HDD, why not install macOS onto a USB flash drive and use that purely so you can use the iMac in Target Display Mode?

To do this, follow these steps:

1. Boot your iMac from the USB flash drive
2. Ensure the other Mac is also booted up and logged into a user account
3. Connect the two Macs with a Mini DisplayPort or Thunderbolt cable
4. Press <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd> on the keyboard of the iMac (i.e. The one you want to use as a display).

For more information you should read [Use your iMac as a display with Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204592)

Comment: Yes I was thinking of doing this, but I posted this just incase that there was another solution. Could you tell me more about booting off a USB? I know how to install an OS off a USB but not about using the USB as a replacement for the HDD.

Comment: Take a look at [How to set up and use an external Mac startup disk](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202796). Keep in mind that any macOS version from Snow Leopard 10.6.1 supports Target Display Mode, although depending on your exact model of 27" 2009 iMac, it _may_ not support booting from an OS earlier than Snow Leopard 10.6.3.